# How to graph a count of HTTP request per minute with Prometheus & Nodejs

Tags: node.js, prometheus, promql

I have nodejs app and need to graph a count of HTTP request per minute. Install [prom-client], with using a Counter. Now i have graph with total count of HTTP request. But idk how to graph per minute.

First option - Im considering is prometheus collect the metric once a minute, later resetting the value. What do u think?

Second option - using Increase, but i got float value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper approach is to use [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function for the [counter metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter). For example, the following query returns per-minute increase per each [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) matching `foo` [filter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering):

```
increase(foo[1m])
```

If this query is used for building graph in Grafana, then every point on the graph shows counter increase over the last minute, which ends at the given point.

Prometheus may return unexpected results from `increase()` function because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). Prometheus developers are aware of this issue and are going to solve it eventually - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

P.S. you can use an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) if you need exact results from the `increase()` function, without extrapolation and missing counter increases.

Comment: Does VictoriaMetrics have an agent for nodejs?

Comment: VictoriaMetrics understands Prometheus scrape configs - https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-scrape-prometheus-exporters-such-as-node-exporter . There is also vmagent, which can be used for scraping Prometheus-compatible targets - https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html